# Applying google_translator to a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, data-science, google-translate

I am trying the following. I am applying a detect and translate function to a column containing free text variable which are the professional role of some customers:

```
from langdetect import detect
from google_trans_new import google_translator  

#simple function to detect and translate text 
def detect_and_translate(text,target_lang='en'):

    result_lang = detect(text)

    if result_lang == target_lang:
       return text 

    else:
       translator = google_translator()
       translate_text = translator.translate(text,lang_src=result_lang,lang_tgt=target_lang)
       return translate_text 
df_processed['Position_Employed'] = df_processed['Position_Employed'].replace({'0':'unknown', 0:'unknown'})
df_processed['Position_Employed'] = df_processed['Position_Employed'].apply(detect_and_translate)
```

But I am getting the following error;

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 433 (char 432)

I have tried to update the solution from this link but it did not work to editing line 151 in google_trans_new/google_trans_new.py which is: response = (decoded_line + ']') to response = decoded_line

[Python google-trans-new translate raises error: JSONDecodeError: Extra data:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68214591/python-google-trans-new-translate-raises-error-jsondecodeerror-extra-data)

What can I do?